# How to setup Express for Aurelia Routing?

Tags: express, aurelia

How do I specify a catchall or actually a catch[most] for express so when the user selects refresh on a page that is actually contained in the app bundle, the GET doesn't fail.

home.html

```
<a href="profile">profile</a>
```

app.js

```
 config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home' },
      { route: ['profile'], name: 'profile', moduleId: './profile/profile'}
    ]);
```

If I click on the profile link, the URL shows localhost://profile and the page renders correctly without performing a GET because the requested resource was bundled in the initial GET.  But lets say I refresh the page with localhost://profile, then it makes a server GET request for that page.

If on the server I specify something like:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.use('/profile', express.static(__dirname));
```

It works properly.  I was anticipating some type of catch all formatting so I don't have to add every possible route for an app with all routes bundled.  Something like:

```
app.use('/*', express.static(__dirname));
```

Then the following to capture GET's for another app

```
app.use('/othercoolapp/*', express.static(__dirname)+'/othercoolapp/');
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: you don't have to create routes in your server. You just have to configure pushState navigation. Something like https://gist.github.com/therebelrobot/747953c392d8a6ed5aaf#file-gistfile1-js-L28

Comment: I do have config.options.pushState = true; but when the user hits refresh on the browser with a client side route in the URL, it will request that route from the server. (which it does not find because it is now bundled)

Comment: Looks like someone else ran into the same issue, with the author of Aurelia coming to the same conclusion. I need to serve the base app for all internal client side URL's. https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/157 . I just don't know how to specify some type of regex catch for routes within an app on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue you're encountering applies to every single page application framework and library with pushState routing enabled.

Above your `app.listen` or equivalent line of code in the file that bootstraps your Express server, add something like this:

```
app.get('*', function(request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

The general idea is that this generic wildcard route will capture all URL requests and send the `index.html` file. This allows Aurelia to handle its own routing.